# Hash Key Facebook API. Android for release mode not debug. MAC OS

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key, keytool

Well.. first of all, sorry for my english..
The api facebook works perfectly in the emulator but when i put it on a mobile it doesnt work.. just open and close the window.. so.. 
I found this 2 commands to generate the Hash Key but i dont know witch one is the correct or what im doing wrong, because i write any password and the command works but at the mobile not..

This is for debug mode.. and the password is default "android"

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore /Users/user/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

This is for release mode.. and the password is the password of your signing key..

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore /Users/user/Desktop/testsing | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Thank you!!

Comment: `but i dont know witch one is the correct` I think both will be correct..make sure you add both keys in your facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to bu sure 100%

1. Go to Your folder on command prompt with Java\bin like example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>
2. Prepare your commands

from facebook developer tutorial:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
>   base64

if you have any problem with openssl you can download it and install example on C:\OpenSSL and then

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore
>   %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64